# Formatting tactic style proof steps

Tags: typography

I'm currently writing a proofs where I need to apply simple mechanical processes in each step. I've currently got the following to work, but the latex is very "hacky" and brittle.

[image: example of proof steps]

The best way to think about this is a pen and paper version of Coq, with tactics on the right with the context on the left.

My current code looks something like

```latex
\usepackage{pfsteps}

\newcommand{\pf}[2]{\usepfcounter[#1]\ $#2$ &\hphantom{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}\\}
\newcommand{\pfstep}[3]{\midrule \usepfcounter[#2]\ $#3$ & \text{#1}\\}

...

\resetpfcounter
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{array}{p{0.6\textwidth}r}     
        \pf{1}{5(n + 1) = 15}
        \pfstep{By distributivity \pfref{1}}
            {2}{5n + 5 = 15}
        \pfstep{By subtraction of 5 \pfref{2}}
            {3}{5n = 10}
        \pfstep{By something wrong \pfref{3}}
            {4}{n = 10}
            \pf{5}{5 = 1}
    \end{array}
\end{equation*}
```

My question is whether there is a better way to achieve the same thing.

In specific I would like to have more flexibility in the content of each proof step. Currently adding too much to either tactic description or context will break the implementation.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at the package `witharrows`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. `witharrows` looks like a very interesting package that I may potentially use in a later project (when appropriate). 

It doesn't quite suit my needs as lots of the proofs I'm writing are not as sequential as the example I gave. e.g. step 20 might need assumptions shown in steps 9 and 19. This is why I'm using the `pfsteps` package for tracking items in context.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming across this in the future. This was my solution

```latex
\newcommand{\pf}[2]{\item $#2$ \pflabel{#1}}
\newcommand{\pfstep}[3]{\\\vspace{-0.3cm}\hrulefill\vspace{-0.1cm}\item $#3$ \pflabel{#2} \BY{#1}}
\begin{pfsteps*}
            \pf{1}{5(n + 1) = 15}
        \pfstep{distributivity \pfref{1}}
            {2}{5n + 5 = 15}
        \pfstep{subtraction~of~5~\pfref{2}}
            {3}{5n = 10}
        \pfstep{something~wrong~\pfref{3}}
            {4}{n = 10}
            \pf{5}{5 = 1}
\end{pfsteps*}
```

[image: output from above latex]

Comment: Fine. // Please complete both code examples by adding \documentclass, \usepackage (!), \begin and \end{document}. I.e. make it ready to copy and compile. Thanks